# Winform application freezes

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm new to developing Winform application (using C# .NET)

My application will freeze and sometimes even showing "not responding" when there are too many operations running behind, especially when it involves a lot of data reading/writing to/from database. The application did NOT crash though, it just freeze until the all code behind were finish executing.

My question is, how do I "unfreeze" the application. For example, the user can still click the "cancel" button to terminate whatever the operation is running, or show a progress bar or something like that?

Comment: You could have a look at Backgroundworkers to STOP your program from freezing.

Comment: Yup, background workers are the solution to all of these problems. They support cancellation, updating on progress (for a progress bar), and won't freeze your app.

Comment: Agree. Look at BackgroundWorker and at async/await. Learn about asynchrony in general.

Answer (score 6):

Your application freezes because it has single thread, which is responsible both for drawing UI and doing other 'heavy' operations (reading/writing to database). When thread is busy with database, it cannot refresh UI. You should perform 'heavy' operations in background thread(s). Thus main thread will be responsible only for refreshing UI and it will be always ready to do that. Use [`BackgroundWorker`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) component to run some operations on background threads.

Suggested reading: [BackgroundWorker Class Sample for Beginners](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/99143/BackgroundWorker-Class-Sample-for-Beginners) and [How to: Use a Background Worker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

A windows application will stop working if you are using a System.Timers.Timer.

To fix this, change System.Timers.Timer by  System.Windows.Forms.Timer

Greetings